# Change part numbering to A, B, C, ... instead of I, II, III,

Tags: sectioning, numbering, parts

How can I configure the `\part` command to use A, B, C, ... to label parts, instead of I, II, III, ... Or is this bad practice?

Comment: Not bad practice, just be careful.  You may end up being a little ambiguous (for example, appendices use letters)

Comment: Also, [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Nice to be here. True, it might not appear very consistent when the appendix also is also partitioning in letters. I'll probably not do it.

Answer (score 7):

```
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
```

Comment: We all know that this has been asked before, don't we? ;)

Comment: @tohecz To be honest, in the possible "original" question `\thepart` as well as `\Alph` were missing before my edit.

Comment: @lockstep I see. Still, the right action is of course to find it an improve it, since the question is _essentially_ the same.